# Automatically migrate JSON data to newest version of JSON schema

Tags: c++, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a service running on my linux machine that reads data stored in a .json file when the machine is booting. The service then validates the incoming JSON data and modifies specific system configurations according to the data. The service is written in C++ and for the validation im using https://github.com/pboettch/json-schema-validator.

In development it was easy to modify the JSON schema and just adapt the data manually. I've started to use semantic versioning for my JSON schema and included it the following way:

JSON schema:

```
{
  "$id": "https://my-company.org/schemas/config/0.1.0/config.schema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  // Start of Schema definition
}
```

JSON data:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://my-comapny.org/schemas/config/0.1.0/config.schema.json",
  // Rest of JSON data
}
```

With the addition of the version, I am able to check if a version mismatch exists before validating.

What I am looking for is a way to automatically migrate the JSON data to match the newer schema version, if a version mismatch is identified. Is there any way to automatically achieve this, or is the only way to manually edit the JSON data to match the schema?

Since I plan on releasing this as open source I would really like to include some form of automatic migration so I can just ask the user if he wants to migrate to conform to the newest schema version instead of throwing an error, if a version mismatch was identified.

Comment: You'd typically load the file into a data structure. If you serialize that data structure again, it should automatically have the latest schema.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt could you perhaps elaborate that a bit more? Not sure how that would work, especially when adding for example a new keyword to the schema

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It sounds like older versions won't be supported, so loading in old versions and then saving out new versions doesn't look viable.

Comment: Isn't this about loading older but still supported versions and converting them to the newest one?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the plan was to keep only the current schema, but if there was a way to automatically migrate by keeping the older versions of the schema available I would be open to try that, as I've mentioned I have no idea how to achieve that by simply serializing the created data structure

Comment: There is no way to determine how to load an older (unknown!) scheme, based on the current scheme. Apart from simple structural changes, there might be any number of semantic changes that need to be taken into account.

Comment: You need to store version information as part of your data. Then you can build something like this that looks at the version of the data being loaded and the version of the current software and then runs all the migrations to bring the version of the data up to scratch. https://github.com/Weingartner/Migrations.Json.Net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for is something which will need to make assumptions to work.

This is an age old problem and similar for databases. You can have schema migrations generated with many simple changes, but this is not viable if you wish to translate existing data automatically too.

Let's look at a basic example. You rename a field.
How would a tool know you've renamed a field vs removed an old one and added a new one? It essentially, cannot.

So, you need to write your migrations by hand.

You could use JSON transformation tools like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) or [fx](https://github.com/antonmedv/fx) to create migration scripts without writing it in code, which may or may not be preferable. (jq has a steeper learning curve but it's also very powerful.)

Comment: So what you're saying is that there is no way to react in C++ to the countless possibilites of a change in a JSON schema? So by using jq or fx I could offer a migration script to the user, that when executed automatically migrates his data? But the user would have to install either jq or fx locally to make this work, correct?

Comment: I'm saying it sounds like you're asking for something that can work out what you want without any context. The programming language you use isn't a factor. If YOU wrote the migration script at the same time you updated the schema, you could then use the migration script to accept previous versions of the data structure. JSON Schema doesn't factor into this.

Comment: I think i get it now, so instead of creating a script that analyzes the diff between the schema and the data to react to the found diff it would be more realistic to define the exact steps necessary in the script to be compatible with the new schema version. And by including for example a switch case in the script I could react to different inputs (different versions) by providing each with the steps necessary to migrate?

So for example if i add a new field to the schema, i would simply add the field to the data, which would be hard-coded in the script?

Comment: Yes. A diff of a schema isn't going to tell you how you should change the data.